# Reading in WAV file into Java, attaining same values as MATLAB or SciPy

Tags: java, matlab, javasound

The question of reading .WAV files in and putting them into an array in Java has been asked on here numerous times.  I've looked at dozens of ways of doing so.  What I am trying to do is obtain the same values that are produced opening a WAV file with MATLAB's native WAVread function.  The particular file I am trying to analyze (in an effort to perform signal processing) is in stereo, with a sample rate of 10000 Hz and is a 32-bit float (which I suspect is part of the problem).

In MATLAB, all of the values for this particular file are in Double format, and the maximum value is 3.0991 and the minimum vale is -3.0530.  I also get these same values in Python using the scipy.io.wavfile.read package.

When utilizing the following Java code to read the file in and then convert it into a type Double array:

```
public static double[] toDoubleArray(byte[] byteArray){
    int times = Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
    double[] doubles = new double[byteArray.length / times];
    for(int i=0;i<doubles.length;i++){
        doubles[i] = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray, i*times, times).getDouble();
    }
    return doubles;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {

Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("").toAbsolutePath();
   File file = new File(path + "/antonio_deep_fast_1.wav");
   
   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);

   int read;
   byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
   try {
    while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
       {
           out.write(buff, 0, read);
       }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
   out.flush();
   byte[] audioBytes = out.toByteArray();
   
   for(byte byteMe:audioBytes)
       System.out.println(byteMe);
   
  double[]doubles = toDoubleArray(audioBytes);
```

I get values as high as 8 and as low as -9.  I've had similar issues with other adaptions of Java's AudioInputStream class, while if I try to use the [Java Wav File IO](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html) package, it does not support the 32-bit float WAV file.

I have probably spent over a dozen hours trying to get this to read in properly.  Part of the issue, no doubt, is my improper understanding of the nature of WAV files.  Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction to read the file in a similar way MATLAB (or scipy) does?

Comment: 32 bits is `float` not `double` which is 64 bits. You may also need to set the `ByteOrder` of the `ByteBuffer`

Comment: If you want to load 32-bit .wav's, you'll need to get a library that supports this. Or, you could convert the files to 16-bit with a tool such as Audacity. The internal data can vary a lot. 16-bit PCM has int values with the range of a short, can be signed or unsigned, I think. I usually convert all sound data to signed normalized PCM (-1 to 1 floats) before doing any significant processing. Are the high and low values you give ones that reflect the volume levels or the possible range that Matlab supports?